# Connecting the first view with tabbar controller

Tags: xcode, storyboard, tabbar, tabbarcontroller

I accidently deleted the connection from the tabbar controller to the first view (the view loaded when the application is loaded). I cannot find how to reconnect this first view. Can anyone help.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you know how to set Segue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is as easy to *set the Segue from one view controller to another*.

- Drag a segue from your master (tab bar view controller) to your sub view controller and set "`viewcontrollers segue`" segue.

Refer link  https://youtu.be/a8OJyUtcJZk which will show how you can achieve this.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: @ Jan Greve, thanks for your suggestion, Copied that.

Comment: I also thought so, but when connecting like this the first screen running the app is black. The first view does not show up.

Comment: Ok, found it, just had to make the tabbar controller first view again! This was it!! Thanks so much.